# APC and Drupal benchmark

Tags: drupal-6, apc

I install apc to my debian on localhost. I tested my drupal site performance with "ab -n 500 -c 10 http://localhost/mydrupalsite" , but I see that there is no change on "request per second". I looked php.info and apc is active. also I added extension=apc.so to my php.ini file. After I restarted the apache.

How can I understand my apc installation is succesfull?
If it is succesfull, why there is no change on test result?

Answer (score 0):

When you install APC on your server, it contains an apc.php file, copy this file or symlink the file to your webroot (in this case, `http://localhost/apc.php`).
Viewing this file will give you insight into what APC is caching, if anything, and if there are cache hits/misses. You can also clear the APC cache from this file.